# new Event('build') vs new CustomEvent('build')

Tags: javascript

On this MDN page [Creating and Triggering Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) it shows an example of creating event with `Event` or `CustomEvent`. It explains that `CustomEvent` allows for custom details, but other than that, it doesn't say much.

So, what is the difference? If I'm creating a generic scroll event, should I use `CustomEvent`? Or is it only for events not exist in javascript?

Also, I noticed that `MouseEvent` is also a child of `Event`, so if I'm creating a click event, I can just use `new MouseEvent('click')`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From that guide:

> To add more data to the event object, the `CustomEvent` interface exists and the `detail` property can be used to pass custom data.

You can use `Event()` for anything. If you want to attach *custom data*, you use `CustomEvent('eventName', {data})`.

And yes, for mouse-events, you should use `MouseEvent`.

Comment: If I can use Event for anything, what advantage is using MouseEvent over Event for a click event? And is there a situation where I would need to use Event explicitly?

Comment: @BigName run them in the console and look at the difference. `MouseEvent` includes all the pointer data; `Event` is just a generic event.

Comment: Also IE11 doesn't support `Event()`.

Answer (score 2):

In all modern browsers:

```js
const ev = new Event('foo')
ev.whatever = 123
console.log('event:', ev.whatever)
```

We can simply use `Event` directly like that, or even extend from `Event` to make a custom event:

```js
class MyEvent extends Event {
  whatever = 123

  constructor() {
    super('my-event', {bubbles: true, composed: true, cancelable: false})
  }
}

someElement.dispatchEvent(new MyEvent()) // simple and done.
```

Nowadays there is absolutely no need for `CustomEvent` to even exist, and we can just use `Event`.

---

In the past, it may not have been possible to extend from `Event` using pre-ES6 `function` classes, but this limitation has long since been overcome in all browsers, and `class`es can extend from native classes.